# JavaEEアプリケーションに対して外部から設定情報を渡したい

Tags: java, java-ee

Wildfly上で動作するJavaEEアプリケーションに対して、アプリケーションの外部から任意の設定情報を渡したいです。
例えばweb.xmlだと、warファイルのbuildが必要になってしまうので、NGです。
Wildflyの再起動程度で反映できるような仕組みを探しています。

Wildflyの管理画面から、Configuration→System Propertiesで、何やら自由に設定できそうな画面が開くのですが、これが使えたりするのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Propertiesは用途として適切です。

WildFlyに限らずJava EEアプリケーションであれば、他にはJNDIを使うこともできます。
値の取得を間接化することができます。

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
String valu = (String) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/hoge/fuga");
```

WildFlyのJNDI設定方法はこちらです。
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JNDI+Reference
完全に外部化するならRemoteの方となります。

JNDI自体についてはこちらが参考になります。
今さら人に訊けない JNDI: 第 1 回 「JNDI ってなんだっけ？」 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/websphere/library/was/was_jndi/1.html

OSの環境変数に設定して、`System.getenv()`で取得することもできます。

Answer (score 0):

用途として適切かどうか分かりませんが、System Propertiesの値は`System.getProperty()`で取得できることがわかりました。